# A question about Sun disk deformation

Tags: the-sun, atmospheric-effects

Suppose the Sun rises and due to refraction the Sun's disc gets deformed. Let the center of the sun be $O$ and $OL$, $OR$, $OT$, $OB$ be the distances from the center of the disc to the edges in the direction $L$eft, $R$ight, $T$op and $B$ottom ($L$, $R$, $T$, $B$ are the farthest points from the center of the disc to their direction due to the deformation of the solar disk). How to find which of the 4 distances is bigger and which is smaller?

Thanks in advance for your answers

Comment: Do you want to measure it? Take a photo and measure it. Do you want to calculate it? Then you need a refraction model to calculate the apparent altitude of each point.

Comment: The question is not unclear, although it has taken about 5 minutes for me to understand. It is border case "too broad", see the comment above.